# Difference Between . venv/bin/activate and ./venv/bin/activate

Tags: python, linux, shell, virtualenv

all

I have a question about an format that to run shell script
I encounter this problem is that I setup a virtual environment

But when I type

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

The code has no problem and run it successfully.But I know the other way to run it using

```
 ./venv/bin/activate
```

the bash prompt an error saying I don't have permission to do that.

I don't know what's the difference between them, any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `activate` script created by virtualenv isn't actually a standard script for executing anything, but it's something that defines further environment variables to an existing `bash` session.  Note the comment in that file:

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly
```

The `. venv/bin/activate` is actually a synonym to [`source`](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)`venv/bin/activate`.  In essence, what virtualenv does is to execute a number of statements in the *current* shell (sourcing the contents of the file into here), rather than starting a new shell process as if you would execute a binary (i.e. `./venv/bin/python`).

Comment: another way to think of sourcing files is like `#include /path/to/envVarFile`. (Depending on your language). Good luck to all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick apply, another question  is, is " . runfile" this format that I can use everywhere?, because when I use" vim newfile" , and write some shell script in it, I can't use". newfile" to run the script in shell, it says no such file or directory, like your answer, I should use " source newfile" first and then use". newfile" to run it?

Comment: You need to write out the file to disk before you can actually use the file.  `vim` by default does not create `newfile` unless `:w` (or equivalent) is called in cmdline mode.  Also there are no difference between `. $file` vs `source $file`, they both execute the file in-place of the current shell.

Comment: right, thanks a lot, now I get from @Hackworth that The . command is essentially an alias for the source.  but I indeed :wq it before I try to run it, so I don't know how can I use ". newfile", because I have ever used it in this way, but script is written by other people, I try in my way, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try a more simple example, maybe like so: `echo $FOO` and see that an empty line, then create a file named `foo` (in vim or whatever) with following: `export FOO=1`, then `. foo`, then `echo $FOO`.